# Test questions about logical reasoning?

Tags: discussion

I apologise if anyone is offended, but would someone please explain the downvotes for such questions as https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15755/what-can-be-inferred-about-merit-goods-test-2-q19-p-119-by-mark-shepherd?

These questions originate from a book for law admissions test that focuses on and stresses 'logical reasoning' and inference, so I'd appreciate advice and feedback from philosophers, who may be more experienced and skilled on these questions involving more than plain reading comprehension, than fluent Anglophones without philosophy training. Is this fine? I'd be grateful to deepen my ['logic — the nature of reasoning and inference'](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here through these questions.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that these questions do involve logical reasoning and inference, the parts you are asking about are not minimized down to the part that involves that. Instead, you're asking us to help you increase your reading comprehension in general by reading multiple paragraphs of text and then explaining to you why your textbook has selected an answer as correct.

Does this mean we never help people understand what a text is saying?

## No, but we are here to help people understand *philosophy* -- not any random scrap of writing that also happens to invoke inference and logical reasoning on some level.

To give some examples of things that don't fit philosophy.se that I have personal interest in:

1. Reading comprehension questions for Japanese.
2. Programming questions
3. Database design questions
4. Questions about how to use my Macbook Air (I had a PC until April).

All of those *involve* logic to some extent. But none of them fit here, because they aren't about logic or philosophy.